# IBrokers Data persistence

Tags: r, ibrokers

I am trying to store persistent values using the `reqRealTimeBars()` function of the `IBrokers` library in order to call some trading logic in the `eWrapper` function.  I have searched the list and gone over Jeff Ryan's slides from various talks he has given.  The subject is touched upon, but I have yet to see a complete answer.  Can someone help elaborate on Jeff's response to this old post https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-finance/2011q3/008242.html

Can someone show me how to rbind an object in the .Data environment of IBrokers to maintain an updated xts object of market data and signals?

```
eWrapper.RealTimeBars <- function(nbars=1, nsymbols=1) {
  eW <- eWrapper(NULL)  # use basic template

  eW$realtimeBars <- function(curMsg, msg, timestamp, file, ...) 
  {
    id <- as.numeric(msg[2])
    data <- eW$get.Data("data") #[[1]]  # list position of symbol (by id == msg[2])
    data[[id]][1] <- as.numeric(msg[3])
    data[[id]][2:8] <- as.numeric(msg[4:10])
    eW$assign.Data("data", data)
    c(curMsg, msg)
  }
  return(eW)
}
```

Thanks in advance.